# Problems with null / 0 returned values from parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I got problem when I call query from parse.com website
When I check returned values from this site I only got 'null' value for string and '0' for integers ...
and this is my code :

```
PFQuery *queryVersion=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ver"];

[queryVersion getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"6AxF9PpLSu" block:^(PFObject* object,NSError* error){


    if (!error) {
      int ver = [[object objectForKey:@"ver"]intValue];

        versionServer=ver;
    }

}];
```

I'm sure that i'm connected to parse.com as i can get pic file in another class and it's working

Here's the picture of my class named 'ver' in parse.com
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98796925/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-21%20at%209.16.03%20PM.png

I just wanna get values in 'ver' column ...

Comment: The query must be `[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HomeButton"]` not "ver", which is what the table name looks like (truncated) in the image.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced". Your image is also broken.